# Facebook: create image from html and share it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I have used before facebook's SDK to share the content of my website like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Your Website Title</title>
    <!-- You can use Open Graph tags to customize link previews.
    Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
  <meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />
  <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
  <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
  <meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  <!-- Your share button code -->
  <div class="fb-share-button" 
    data-href="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" 
    data-layout="button_count">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, in order to share the right image on facebook you must define it in the `<meta property="og:image" content="" />` tag.
This time I have a different situation, I can't get my image from the server because it's dynamic, I need to create it from HTML bloc.
I already have a jquery function that takes a HTML content and create an image out of it but I don't know how to share it on Facebook!!
**So my question is**: Is there a solution to share an image on Facebook or Twitter after creating it using javascript ?
and thanks in advance.